# Whats is a good API to get the polygons that define the boundaries for US cities?

Tags: gis

Whats is a good API to get the polygons that define the boundaries for US cities?

Have looked at google, but it seems to only return a boundary box.

Comment: You should ask those questions at Gis Stackexchange http://gis.stackexchange.com. See this related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/where-can-i-find-a-shapefile-of-city-boundaries-in-the-us